# mysql - working with big table 200k rows

Tags: php, mysql

i'm using this code to genarate html table from mysql tabe. table has 200k rows.

```html
$view->ach = $db->Query("SELECT from_unixtime(`date`), `aav_id`, `aav_domain`, `aav_word`, `aav_referer`, `aav_ip`, `aav_country` 
FROM aav_views 
where aav_user_id=$USER_ID
ORDER BY date DESC
");
```

but it's not working. web browser saying

"The page isn’t working
www.mysite.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500 "

(not the 500 internal server error)

i add a limit to sql query like this

```html
$view->ach = $db->Query("SELECT from_unixtime(`date`), `aav_id`, `aav_domain`, `aav_word`, `aav_referer`, `aav_ip`, `aav_country` 
FROM aav_views 
where aav_user_id=$USER_ID
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1000
");
```

now it is working fine. but i need to use without limit. i need to query all 200k rows

Comment: try fetching in batches (or 'chunks') instead of all at once. slower, but doesn't hammer resources as much. basically, like paging through a long list of data.

Comment: Is it necessary to show 200K rows at a time?

Comment: yes i need to get all rows.

Comment: You need to batch it, you can't get them all in one shot.

Comment: If you post the exact error output with came with the 500 error, maybe someone can give you a detailed fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to handle such a large result set from MySQL is to use something called *pagination*.  With pagination, you might only retrieve records 100 or 1000 at a time.  This eliminates the problem of crashing your web server or web page with too much information.

MySQL has two keywords which are well suited to handle this problem.  The first one, `LIMIT`, you already know, and it controls how many total records appear in the result set.  The second one is `OFFSET`, and it specifies the position in the result set from which to begin taking records.

To give you an example, if you wanted to return the second 100 records from your table, you would issue the following query:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(date), aav_id, aav_domain, aav_word, aav_referer, aav_ip, aav_country
FROM aav_views 
where aav_user_id=$USER_ID
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 100
```

Typically, the user controls the offset by paging through a UI containing the results from the query.

Comment: also i need to count the rows. how can i count it without geting 500 error

Comment: Counting the rows can be accomplished with a simple `SELECT COUNT(*)` query.  This should not overload your network/server, but could place a strain on MySQL.  Even so, a single full table scan of 200K is not particularly bad.

Comment: i did it with SELECT COUNT(*) as total  but getting 500 error

Comment: Can you even execute the query from Workbench?  `500` error is generic and just means something went wrong.  I doubt that the problem is with MySQL.  Please check your error logs.

Comment: its happening only when big tables like 10000+ rows. when table has like 5000, 6000 rows. count is working fine

Comment: Without seeing error output, I can't help you, and you also can't figure out what the root cause is.

Comment: Maybe your server is crashing because of overload